# Unable to run pnpm commands using gradle-node-plugin

Tags: gradle, pnpm, gradle-node-plugin

I have this settings in gradle:

```
configure([project(':myProject')]) {
    apply plugin: "com.github.node-gradle.node"
    node {
        version = '18.18.2'
        download = true
    }
}
```

My version is supposed to work with pnpm

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.node-gradle:gradle-node-plugin:7.0.1"
}
```

And this is my task

```
task buildMablDriver(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn ":myProject:npm_run_build"
}
```

When I run gradle I get a

```
> Task with path ':myProject:pnpm_run_build' not found in project
```